# Maximize the spread of all nurses in Scheduling

Tags: python, or-tools

```
    model.Maximize(
        sum(shift_requests[n][d] * shifts[( n, d)] for n in all_nurses
            for d in all_days))
```

Curious how I could change the above (which is optimizing for shift requests) to the below, which would optimize for the spread. I'm trying to actually spread out the assignments as much as possible. Thoughts?

```
    model.Maximize(
        np.std(shifts[( n, d)] for n in all_nurses
            for d in all_days))
```

Comment: What do you want to put between assignments ? non working days ?

Comment: Correct. Just need the assignments to be spread as far apart across the 12 nurses as possible. 12 nurses on call 52 weeks of the year.

Comment: 1) you mean for each nurse, the assiments must be spread as much as possible ? 2) how do you compare w.w...w vs w..w..w (dots meaning not working) ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what's currently happening. We have 2 or 3 that have short, short, long. Was up late trying to figure it out last night.. is there a way just to plug a "minimum break" in there? that would work for me as well..

Comment: To your point.. maybe it is "Maximizing the minimum" of the not working time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following

You have a list of Booleans: b(i) means mean span between 2 working days is greater or equal than i

1. you need to ensure consistency between b(i) variables: b(i) => b(i-1)
2. if nurse n is working on day d, and b(i) is true, then work[n, d + i - 1] is false. Encoded as `model.AddBoolOr(work[n, d].Not(), b(i).Not(), work[n, d + i - 1].Not()]` for all the relevant `n`, `d`, `i`.
3. maximize i where b(i) is true. A crude solution would be just `model.Maximize(sum(b(i)))`. Maybe this can be improved.